# Correctly updating Object in React.js State without using spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The spread operator `...` is an experimental level feature according to Visual Studio or ReSharper Intellisense and I am using ECMAScript 2015:
[image]

I am using Babel and I see the spread operator in the transpiled source:
[image]

So I trying to replace spread operator functionality for updating on object in React state with Object.assign.

Use the spread operator I can update the state of my object with:

```
setInputs(prevInputs => ({ ...prevInputs, [name]:value}));
```

This works great. Now I want to remove the spread operator to maximize cross browser compatibility.

Unfortunately when I try and update a value change to a property in my state object using other methods I get the error:

> A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled

I understand what this error message means, what I cannot understand is what is different about my object update, compared to the spread operator, here is the ways I have tried to replace the spread operator:

```
if (value) {
    //try to update state with value that is not undefined
    setInputs(prevInputs => Object.assign({}, prevInputs)[name] = value);

    //another try to update state with value that is not undefined
    setInputs(prevInputs => prevInputs[name] = value);
}
```

I do not understand what is going on here, the spread operator is creating a new object:

```
const originalObj = {
    name: '',
};
const spread = {...originalObj};
console.log('is originalObj === spread', originalObj === spread); //no they are not
```

How is my Object.assign way of replacing spread not closing mimicing the spread operator object creation?

Comment: Use Babel instead, and you won't have to worry about browser compatibility at all. Don't cripple the readability of your code for the sake of obsolete browsers. Also, object spread is ES2018, not ES2015. (Actually, since you're using React, shouldn't your code be getting transpiled anyway?)

Comment: If you want the `originalObj` to be the same (`===`) as the other object, the only way to do so is to actually mutate the `originalObj`, which should not be done (in React, at least)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am using Babel and when I look at the Transpiled code I see the Spread operator in the source file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mimic spread and assign a new property to the object, you need to

(1) Create a shallow copy of the original object

(2) Assign a new value to that copied object

(3) Return the copied object

When you do

```
setInputs(prevInputs => Object.assign({}, prevInputs)[name] = value);
```

you're creating a shallow copy, but then you're *returning the assignment*, so the return value is the value of the assignment, not the copied object. The above code is equivalent to

```
setInputs(prevInputs => value);
```

Best to avoid using assignments in expressions - they're almost never what you want.

With

```
setInputs(prevInputs => prevInputs[name] = value);
```

you're doing something a bit similar: you're mutating the existing `prevInputs` object, and returning the `value`. It's equivalent to

```
setInputs(prevInputs => {
  prevInputs[name] = value;
  return value;
});
```

To achieve the shallow copy, set a value on the copied object, and return it, do:

```
setInputs(prevInputs => {
  const newInputs = Object.assign({}, prevInputs); // Shallow copy
  newInputs[name] = value; // Assign new value
  return newInputs; // Return copied object
});
```

Or, equivalently:

```
setInputs(prevInputs => Object.assign({}, prevInputs, {[name]: value }));
```

The above works because `Object.assign` returns the new object (the first parameter).

Keep in mind that this avoids object spread syntax (which is ES2018), resulting in the code being compatible with ES2015. To make the code compatible with ES5 (ES2009) will require a lot more work. Either way, to make your code compatible, it's probably best to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to take care of it automatically - this keeps your source files nice and readable, while permitting obsolete browsers to understand the transpiled code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the spread operator is browser compatible according to babel itself.

[image]

Comment: I'd think that should have generated a SyntaxError, or it should have been transpiled correctly. The generated output only works in new browsers.